Why does my flutter app crash while using a classifier trained model?
I use a trained model for audio classification in a flutter app. I use the tflite_audio plugin: ^0.3.0, when I start audio recording the app closes. Works well with a google teachablemachine model. help me
thisi is my code:
class Classification extends StatefulWidget {
  const Classification({super.key});

  @override
  State<Classification> createState() => _ClassificationState();
}

class _ClassificationState extends State<Classification> {
  String _sound = "Clicca sul pulsante per avviare";
  bool _recording = false;
  Stream<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>? result;

  @override
  void initState() {
    TfliteAudio.loadModel(
        model: "assets/model.tflite",
        label: "assets/labels.txt",
        // for Google's Teachable Machine models
        //inputType: 'rawAudio',
        //  for decodedWav models use
        inputType: 'decodedWav',
        numThreads: 1,
        isAsset: true
       );
    super.initState();
  }

  void _recorder() {
    String recognition = "";
    if (!_recording) {
      setState(() {
        _recording = true;
      });
      result = TfliteAudio.startAudioRecognition(
      
       // sampleRate: 44100, //google
       // bufferSize: 22016,

        sampleRate: 16000,
        bufferSize: 2000,
      
      );
      result?.listen((event) {
        recognition = event["recognitionResult"];
      }).onDone(() {
        setState(() {
          _recording = false;
          _sound = recognition.split(" ")[1];
        });
      });
    }
  }

  void _stop() {
    TfliteAudio.stopAudioRecognition();
    setState(() => _recording = false);
  }


the code of error in console is:
V/TfliteAudio( 4294): Recognition started.
W/System.err( 4294): io.reactivex.rxjava3.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: The exception was not handled due to missing onError handler in the subscribe() method call. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input Tensor index: 1
W/System.err( 4294):    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:718)
W/System.err( 4294):    at io.reactivex.rxjava3.internal.functions.Functions$OnErrorMissingConsumer.accept(Functions.java:715)
...
E/AndroidRuntime( 4294):    ... 10 more
I/Process ( 4294): Sending signal. PID: 4294 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
I tried with audio and image metadata, but it keeps crashing. If I use models trained by goggle it works.
